# How can I cancel the effect of {} in untouchable macros?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Assuming that we cannot change the implementation of `\blackbox` that is

```
\def\blackbox#1{{}#1}
```

What should we pass to `\blackbox` such that `$\blackbox{<something we need to pass>}$` produces the same result as `$-y$`? In other words, how can I cancel the effect of `{}` defined in `\blackbox`?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\blackbox#1{{}#1}

\begin{document}
\noindent\huge
$-y$\\ % output that I want to achieve 
$\blackbox{-y}$ % how can I remove the effect of {} in \blackbox?
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Real scenario

I want use `\equ` for representing $-3y=59$ but if I use `\equ{}{-3y}{59}` the output is not identical because of the prefix `{}` defined in `\equ`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs}

\newcommand\specifier{%
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{\quad}c@{\quad}
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{}c}

\newcommand\act[1]{\xrightarrow{\quad\mathclap{\times #1}\quad}}
\newcommand\ope[1]{~\smash{\raisebox{.8\normalbaselineskip}{$#1$}}}
\newcommand\equ[3]{{}#1 & {}#2 & {}=#3}

\begin{document}
$
    \begin{array}{\specifier}
     \equ{3x}{+3y}{7} & \act{1} & \equ{3x}{+3y}{7}            \\[\jot]
     \equ{3x}{}{22}   & \act{3} & \equ{3x}{}{66}   & \ope{-}  \\\cmidrule{5-7}
         &&           &         & \equ{}{-3y}{59}             \\[\jot]
         &&           &         & \equ{}{y}{-59/3}            \\
    \end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a math atom:

```
$\blackbox{{-y}}$
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
\def\gobble#1{}
$\expandafter\gobble\blackbox{-y}$
```

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer This answer does in fact more closely answer your _question_ (as stated in the title) although Herbert's answer is better for the particular application.